# Trying to extend one class to another

Tags: java, class

Currently I have a working class called Humane32 and I want to extend my class Fysikere42 with this one, I have 2 arguments in Human, age and name, and one additional on the Fysikere42. The Humane32 class is currently looking like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Humane32{
    public static class Human{
        private static final List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Rutger","Oscar","Aram","Noak","Hilda","Dahl");
        public Random rand=new Random();
        public String name;
        public int age;

        public Human(int age, String name){
            this.age=age;
            this.name=name;

        }
        public Human(){
            this.age=rand.nextInt(101);
            this.name=names.get(rand.nextInt(names.size()));
        }

        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }
        public int getAge(){
            return this.age;
        }
        public String toString(){
            return "åldern är:"+this.age+"\n"+"namnet är:"+this.name;
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Human> humaner=new ArrayList<Human>();
        int q;
        for (q=0;q<=15;q++){
            humaner.add(new Human());
            System.out.println(humaner.get(q).toString());
        }

    }
}
```

And my new class is currently looking like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Fysikere42 extends Humane32{
    public static class Fysikerere42{
        public int year;

        public Fysikere42(int age, String name,int year){
            this.age=age;
            this.name=name;
            this.year=year;

        }
        public int getYear(){
            return this.year;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("hej");
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error message, "invalid method declaration, return type required". Where did it go wrong?

Comment: You are getting it on which line of code? You have both `Fysikerere42` and `Fysikere42`, and you have the constructor for the latter inside the former. Please clarify what on earth you're up to here.

Comment: Your nested class `Fysikerere42` is trying to declare a constructor with `public Fysikere42` instead of `public Fysikerere42`.

Comment: public fysikere42(int age....)

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a constructor for `Fysikere42` inside the static inner class `Fysikerere42` since the names do not match it does not read it as a constructor for `Fysikerere42` and hence it is asking for a return type for this method. (Since constructor methods don't have return types but it doesnt think this is a constructor).

Change the name of the constructor to `Fysikerere42`:

```
public class Fysikere42 extends Humane32{
    public static class Fysikerere42{
        public int year;

        public Fysikerere42(int age, String name,int year){
            this.age=age;
            this.name=name;
            this.year=year;

        }
```

Comment: Sorry for stupid mistake, but its actually not working anyway :/

Comment: @A.Maine So post another question about that. I suggest you delete this one, it is futile.

Comment: I cant delete it since people has answered, which I appreciate, sorry for being a retard bringing stupid typos...